# After setting up BasePage.vb and creating a session, I have a strange query string in my URL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010

I was guided by [Nuux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066560/nuux) who was kind enough to help me through the intricate process of localizing my website, and then giving the client the option to manually select their own language by clicking a flag and it lasts for their entire time/session they're on the website.  My website is Visual Studio 2010 / vb / net 4.0.

In doing so, I created a class, **BasePage.vb**.  ALL of my pages are set to inherit: BasePage in their code behind.  Here's a line of interest from BasePage.vb:

```
              'retrieve culture information from session
        Dim culture__1 As String = Convert.ToString(Session([Global].SESSION_KEY_CULTURE))
```

Everything functions great, and Nuux was a perfect help.  I have 1 remaining issue.  When I go to my homepage (or any page), there's a strange query string in there.  I think it's that line in BasePage.vb, more than something on a page's code behind, because it happens even if I open a browser, bypass the homepage by going directly to mydomain/about.aspx.  For instance, just go to the about page and this shows up:

```
  mydomain.com/(S(tp5bafoygn0ahwdp1mh0x4v5))/about.aspx
```

But the languages work great and last the entire session!  What is the **(S(tp5bafoygn0ahwdp1mh0x4v5))** ?  Should I get rid of it, and if so, how would I go about doing this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called a [cookieless session identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx).

Change

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

to

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" />
```

In your web.config. Mind you, if you intentionally want a cookieless session (which I would not bother with these days), then the behavior is normal.

Comment: Unbelievable, VCS!  How simple was that?  It was right where you told me it was, so I did what you told me to do, and immediately, those query strings were removed -- and the website functions perfectly!  Thank you very much for taking the time to reply and help me out with your insight.  And another thank you for providing me with the link so I can research it a bit myself.  I really do appreciate your help!  Perfect, clear, and concise response!